# Recommended OpenGL / GLUT Reference

Tags: c++, opengl, reference, glut

**What OpenGL / GLUT reference is good for day to day programming as you learn?**

Ideally I'm looking for something with lots of C++ sample code to help me learn as I develop OpenGL applications as well as details about the APIs similar to what [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library) provides for .net programming.

If there isn't a one stop shop, then please list the set of references I should use and what the strengths of each one is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Red Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321552628) is the standard book on OpenGL. Don't be discouraged by the fact that the Amazon review for the 7th Edition has only two stars; this is because people are disappointed that there isn't more on the newest OpenGL features in the book. Previous editions got more stars.

Another good book is the [OpenGL SuperBible](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321498828).

The [NeHe Tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) are one of the most often cited OpenGL tutorials, with sample code not only in C++ but in many other programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

I learned OpenGL using the [OpenGL Super Bible](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321498828). It's still the best reference for it that I can find.

Answer (score 1):

The [PyOpenGL Documentation](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/index.xhtml#GL) is identical to the OpenGL docs, but far more readable and user-friendly. Have a look.

I also second the [OpenGL SuperBible](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321498828).

Answer (score 1):

I think that by "Glut" you mean "Freeglut".
In this case, you should use this specific reference:

http://jocelyn.frechot.free.fr/freeglut/freeglut_2.6.0-api_0.3.xhtml

It contains latest references for current Freeglut.
This way, you can use special aptitudes of Freeglut (like controlling your own GL loop with glutMainLoopEvent(), which is invaluadble when you're using Freeglut with others libraries.

Answer (score 0):

For all the details about the OpenGL-API there are of course the sdk documentation pages https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/ or you could look into the standard specification itself (which I personally avoid most of the time). This most likely only helps if you already have a basic understanding of how to use the GL. The news section on opengl.org also often links to tutorials and books. Just skimmed through it and found [this tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/). As for OpenGL related books I only know the Super Bible, which I think is okay to get started. When learning OpenGL without any computer graphics knowledge a book on that topic can be very helpful too. A classic would be Coumputer Graphics Principal and Practice by James D. Foley, which is still an excellent read but it doesn't focus much on real time rendering. For that Real-Time Rendering by Akenine-Moller is an excellent choice.